# CPAN installs module and doesn't see it after...cpan database issue?

Tags: database, perl, module, installation, cpan

I have this issue with some Perl modules   on Fedora Linux. They are installed correctly and  not show up in the list after.

For example I run:

```
cpan XML::SAX::Base
```

it produced lengthy output like:

```
-------------------------------------------------
Reading '/root/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Tue, 12 Aug 2014 23:41:02 GMT
Running install for module 'XML::SAX::Base'
Running make for G/GR/GRANTM/XML-SAX-Base-1.08.tar.gz
Checksum for /root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/G/GR/GRANTM/XML-SAX-Base-1.08.tar.gz ok

  CPAN.pm: Building G/GR/GRANTM/XML-SAX-Base-1.08.tar.gz

Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Writing Makefile for XML::SAX::Base
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
cp lib/XML/SAX/Base.pm blib/lib/XML/SAX/Base.pm
cp lib/XML/SAX/Exception.pm blib/lib/XML/SAX/Exception.pm
cp BuildSAXBase.pl blib/lib/XML/SAX/BuildSAXBase.pl
Manifying blib/man3/XML::SAX::Exception.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/XML::SAX::BuildSAXBase.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/XML::SAX::Base.3pm
  GRANTM/XML-SAX-Base-1.08.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make -- OK
Running make test
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 /usr/bin/perl "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-e" "test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/00basic.t ............. ok
t/01exception.t ......... ok
t/01simpledriver.t ...... ok
t/02simplefilter.t ...... ok
t/03chdriver.t .......... ok
t/04chfilter.t .......... ok
t/05dtdhdriver.t ........ ok
t/06lexhdriver.t ........ ok
t/07declhdriver.t ....... ok
t/08errorhdriver.t ...... ok
t/09resoldriver.t ....... ok
t/10dochdriver.t ........ ok
t/11sax1multiclass.t .... ok
t/12sax2multiclass.t .... ok
t/13handlerswitch.t ..... ok
t/14downstreamswitch.t .. ok
t/15parentswitch.t ...... ok
t/16gethandlers.t ....... ok
t/release-pod-syntax.t .. skipped: these tests are for release candidate testing
All tests successful.
Files=19, Tests=137,  1 wallclock secs ( 0.09 usr  0.03 sys +  0.61 cusr  0.11 csys =  0.84 CPU)
Result: PASS
  GRANTM/XML-SAX-Base-1.08.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make test -- OK
Running make install
Manifying blib/man3/XML::SAX::Exception.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/XML::SAX::BuildSAXBase.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/XML::SAX::Base.3pm
Appending installation info to /root/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/perllocal.pod
  GRANTM/XML-SAX-Base-1.08.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make install  -- OK
--------------------------------------------
```

Looks like the module installed. When I run:

```
cpan -l | grep SAX
```

it gives nothing.

If I run installation again:

```
cpan XML::SAX::Base
```

it will install it again.

I guess something wrong with the database, is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Does `/usr/bin/perl -e'use XML::SAX::Base'` give an error?

Comment: What's the output of `echo 'o conf' | cpan | grep  '^ *\(make\|mbuild\)'`? What's the output of `/usr/bin/perl -V:'inst.*lib'`? What's the `@INC` section at the bottom of the output of `/usr/bin/perl -V`?

Comment: /usr/bin/perl -e 'use XML::SAX::Base'
Can't locate XML/SAX/Base.pm in @INC (you may need to install the XML::SAX::Base module) (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at -e line 1.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at -e line 1.

Comment: echo 'o conf' | cpan | grep '^ *\(make\|mbuild\)'
    make               [/usr/bin/make]
    make_arg           []
    make_install_arg   []
    make_install_make_command [/usr/bin/make]
    makepl_arg         []
    mbuild_arg         []
    mbuild_install_arg []
    mbuild_install_build_command [./Build]
    mbuildpl_arg       []

Comment: /usr/bin/perl -V:'inst.*lib'
installarchlib='/usr/lib64/perl5';
installprivlib='/usr/share/perl5';
installsitelib='/usr/local/share/perl5';
installvendorlib='/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl';

Comment: /usr/bin/perl -V:'inst.*lib'

Comment: @INC:
    /usr/local/lib64/perl5
    /usr/local/share/perl5
    /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl
    /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl
    /usr/lib64/perl5
    /usr/share/perl5

Comment: Just want to add, that the problem not only with SAX::Base module...some others can not be installed as well. But some modules are installed...

Comment: Were you `root` when you did `/usr/bin/perl -e 'use XML::SAX::Base'`?

Comment: @ikeami Yes I was `root` running all these commands. I was trying to see where it was copied and run this: `ls /root/.cpan/build/`, which gave me: `.....         XML-SAX-0.99-MCcMz_.yml               YAML-1.01-6h_rWs.yml
SOAP-0.28-32BWma                         XML-SAX-0.99-MRL1Bb
SOAP-0.28-b8X4UC                         XML-SAX-0.99-MRL1Bb.yml`. As I see this (and some other) modules were copied to the wrong location. There are a lot of files like `XML-SAX-0.99-MRL1Bb` there (as many as many times I was trying to install the package). Does it give you any clue?

Comment: `/root/.cpan/build/` is where the modules are built before being installed.

Comment: Does `find /usr -name Base.pm | grep 'XML/SAX/Base.pm$'` return anything? (Make take a while)

Comment: Tried to download and install the module manually...result is the same: installed fine, but cpan doesn't see it after.

Comment: `cpan -l` and `cpan -D` sees it:   `cpan -D XML::SAX::Base``Reading '/root/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Sun, 24 Aug 2014 16:41:02 GMT
XML::SAX::Base
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/share/perl5/App/Cpan.pm line 1151.
 (no description)
 G/GR/GRANTM/XML-SAX-Base-1.08.tar.gz
 Installed: 
 CPAN:      1.08  Not up to date
 Grant McLean (GRANTM)
 grantm@cpan.org`


`[root@localhost XML-SAX-Base-1.08]# cpan -l | grep SAX`
`
...
lib::XML::SAX::Exception 1.08`

Comment: Earlier, you said `cpan -l | grep SAX` returned nothing, now you said it returns a line containing `lib::XML::SAX::Exception`. Now I have no idea what information to trust and what not to trust. Fix your question. Don't forget to add the answers to previously asked questions. Also, include the first line of your `cpan` file.

Comment: Note that lib::XML::SAX::Exception is not the same as XML::SAX::Exception. I mean it's surely XML::SAX::Exception, but it's not installed correctly.

Comment: @ikegami `cpan -l | grep SAX` now returns that XML::SAX::Base is here (before it didn't). May be it happened after cpan upgraded itself. But I stil can't use the module and it installed all the time when I am installing it.

Comment: `[localhost ~]$ cpan -l | grep SAX`
`blib::lib::XML::SAX::Exception 1.08
blib::lib::XML::SAX::Base 1.08
lib::XML::SAX::Exception 1.08
lib::XML::SAX::Base 1.08
build::blib::lib::XML::SAX::Exception 1.08
build::blib::lib::XML::SAX::Base 1.08
build::lib::XML::SAX::Exception 1.08
build::lib::XML::SAX::Base 1.08`

Comment: `.[@localhost ~]$ ./1new_xml_parse.pl 
Can't locate XML/SAX/Base.pm in @INC (you may need to install the XML::SAX::Base module) (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at ./1new_xml_parse.pl line 20.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./1new_xml_parse.pl line 20.`

Comment: @ikegami..also, sorry for confusion. When I said before that `cpan -l | grep SAX`returns nothing, I meant that it returns "nothing about XML::SAX::Base" module....now it returns  something (see above), but I am still not able to use this module...:-(

Comment: ah, the extra .pm found are because of the `.` in `@INC`. Ignore the stuff starting with `lib::` or `blib::`

Comment: Finally, I was able to fix this problem. As I understand, the whole problem was in installation of different parts of Perl in different folders. For example, I had /root/perl5 folder and /home/user1/perl5 folder.I was not able to install modules as a non-root user. I had to switch to root any time, I was installing any module. Then I had to switch back to user when I was creating perl script. Now I moved everything to normal user and it's finally working.

Comment: That is how I did it:
 First under root:
  `su - ;
 rm -fr /home/user/perl5/ ;
 mv -f perl5 /home/user/ ;
 chown -fR  user /home/user/perl5 ;
 chgrp -fR  user /home/user/perl5 ;
 exit `
 Second under user:
  `PATH=$PATH:/home/user/perl5/bin;
  export PERL5LIB=/home/user/perl5/lib/perl5/;`
  Now I can do either  
 `cpan XML::SAX::Base or cpanm XML::SAX::Base` and it is all good and I don't need to switch to root any more every time I install modules!!!

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I was able to fix this problem. As I understand, the whole problem was in installation of different parts of Perl in different folders. For example, I had /root/perl5 folder and /home/user1/perl5 folder.I was not able to install modules as a non-root user. I had to switch to root any time, I was installing any module. Then I had to switch back to user when I was creating perl script. Now I moved everything to normal user and it's finally working.

That is how I did it:

First under root:

```
 su - ; 
  rm -fr /home/user/perl5/ ;
  mv -f perl5 /home/user/ ; 
  chown -fR user /home/user/perl5 ; 
  chgrp -fR user /home/user/perl5 ; 
  exit `
```

Second under user:

```
  PATH=$PATH:/home/user/perl5/bin;
  export PERL5LIB=/home/user/perl5/lib/perl5/;
```

Those two commands you need to enter every time after reboot or use ~/.bashrc

Now I can do either `cpan XML::SAX::Base` or `cpanm XML::SAX::Base` and it is all good and I don't need to switch to root any more every time I install modules!!!

Comment: When you change to 'root' user, be sure to ALWAYS use 'su - root' from you own user account.  If you don't, then 'root' inherits your user ENVironment settings, and will likely install modules in your user folder, BUT with 'root' permission.